# Python classes: exam marks project

Tags: python, function, class, oop, variables

This is my first python mini project after dabbling for one hour. I have zero previous coding experience, and I directly jumped to python classes. I would like to know, is there any improvement that should be made to the code?

```
class student:
    def __init__(self,name,grade,section):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.section = section


    def elon_marks(self):
        english = "89"
        math = "90"
        science = "99"
        print("elon scored" , english, "in english")
        print("elon scored" , math, "in maths")
        print("elon scored" , science, "in science")



    def bill_marks(self):
        english = "55"
        math = "34"
        science = "22"
        print("bill scored" , english , "in english")
        print("bill scored" , math, "in maths")
        print("bill score" ,science, "in science")

elon = student("elon","9th","D") 
bill = student("bill","11th","A") 
elon.elon_marks()
bill.bill_marks()
```

Comment: Omair if you can please tell me what is the thing that you wanted to achieve by writing this code? What's your objective?

Comment: to keep a record of student marks i guess.

Comment: Right now, the information on the students' marks is hard-coded in the methods, and it does not matter whether you call `elon_marks` on `elon` or `bill`. In `__init__`, you define attributes for the instance, like the name and grade. You should do the same for the marks, setting `self.math` etc., and then use those, e.g. `print(self.name, "scored" , self.english , "in english")`

Comment: you don't need separate functions, bill_marks and elno_marks. just create one helper function, marks, and pass in the instance which contains attributes like name and scores already.

Answer (score -1):

Writing functions that are specific to objects (elon, bill) in your class is wrong. Your class should be written to work for a third student as well (and thousands more).

Some hints on how to improve your class:

1. Include marks as your class attributes. Marks can e.g. be stored in a dictionary, where the subject is the key and the mark itself is the value. In your `__init__` function add a line:

```
        self.marks = {} # Empty dictionary
```

2. Add a function to your class to set a mark (you can later improve it to take multiple marks as a list, but here is a simple one:

```
    sub set_mark(self, subject, mark):
        self.marks[subject] = mark
```

3. Put your print statements into a separate function (e.g. called print_marks). That function shall of course use self.name for the name instead of "elon" or "bill". And instead of printing the marks of three subjects, it should loop (iterate) over what is in the marks dictionary. I leave this as an exercise for you to figure it out.
4. Adjust your main function accordingly. Example:

```
elon = Student("elon","9th","D")
elon.set_mark("english", 55)
elon.set_mark("math", 34)
elon.set_mark("science", 22)
elon.print_marks()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this that can make your code easier to read
and also you can use this class in a lot of different ways

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, grade, section):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.section = section
        self.marks = {}

    def insert_new_mark(self, subject, mark):
        if subject not in self.marks:
            self.marks.update({subject: mark})
        else:
            print("Subject is already in marks")


elon = Student("elon", "9th", "D")
bill = Student("bill", "11th", "A")

elon.insert_new_mark("English", 89)
elon.insert_new_mark("Math", 90)
elon.insert_new_mark("Science", 99)


bill.insert_new_mark("English", 55)
bill.insert_new_mark("Math", 34)
bill.insert_new_mark("Science", 22)


print(elon.marks)
print(bill.marks)
```

output:

```
{'English': 89, 'Math': 90, 'Science': 99}
{'English': 55, 'Math': 34, 'Science': 22}
```

Comment: how to use the .lower() method? the problem is when for instance i add English and english both are printed in the subject:mark dictionary.

Comment: in this line:  `self.marks.update({subject: mark})`, change the parameter subject to mark.lower() like this: `self.marks.update({subject.lower(): mark})`